# How to correctly Indent the equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am trying to typeset some equations but the indentation somehow gets messed up.

This is the code:

```
\begin{equation*}
d^{2} = (x_{1}-x_{2})^{2}+(y_{1}-y_{2})^{2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
y'{} & = |BD| = |BF| - |DF| = |BF| - |AE| \\ 
     & = |AB|cos(\alpha) - |OA|sin(\alpha) = -xsin(\alpha) + ycos(\alpha).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

and this is what I am getting:

[image]

How can I fix the indentation?

Comment: What exactly do you wish to achieve? Do you want all the `=` signs to be aligned?

Comment: `equation` environments are unrelated to each others, since they're for independent equations, so each one centers its content. If those two equations following each others are related, then `equation` isn't the right environment for the job. Please clarify what you expected.

Comment: you are using centred, not left aligned/indented equations. but use `\sin` and `\cos` never  `xsin`  which is typeset as x times s times i times n times s

Answer (score 2):

If you want your `=` signs aligned, use a single `align*` environment. Also,

1. Use `\sin` not `sin` to get the proper spacing and shape. Similarly for `\cos`, `\tan`, `\log`, `\ln`, etc.
2. The `{}` after `y'` is unnecessary.
3. For sub- and superscripts that contain only a single character in the braces, the braces are unnecessary (but fine if you prefer to keep them). For example, `d^2` and `d^{2}` produce identical outputs. Same for `x_1` and `x_{1}`. Note that `x_11` is not the same as `x_{11}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
d^{2} &= (x_{1}-x_{2})^{2}+(y_{1}-y_{2})^{2}\\
y'{} &= |BD| = |BF| - |DF| = |BF| - |AE| \\ 
     &= |AB|\cos(\alpha) - |OA|\sin(\alpha) = -x\sin(\alpha) + y\cos(\alpha).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```